# How to place element vertically on mat-list-item when resized?

Tags: html, angular, list, flexbox, angular-material

Trying to make a list of which when resized the text element would be placed vertically on top of each other but they start overlapping when resizing window as seen in the right image. Left image is fullscreen.

[image]

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div matLine>
    <div fxLayout="column">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-md="row">
         <div fxFlex="50"> ---------one--------- </div>
         <div fxFlex="50"> ---------two--------- </div>
       </div>
       <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-md="row">
         <div fxFlex="50"> ---------three---------</div>
         <div fxFlex="50"> ---------four---------</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-list-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `mat-list-item` has a fixed height which is specified by material design. If you need more room, you should use something other than `mat-list`, or break out into multiple list items:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div fxHide.lt-lg>
        <mat-list-item>
            <div matLine>
                <div fxLayout="column">
                    <div fxLayout="row">
                        <div fxFlex="50"> ---------one--------- </div>
                        <div fxFlex="50"> ---------two--------- </div>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="row">
                        <div fxFlex="50"> ---------three---------</div>
                        <div fxFlex="50"> ---------four---------</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-list-item>
    </div>
    <div fxHide.gt-md>
        <mat-list-item>
            <div matLine>
                <div fxLayout="column">
                    <div fxFlex="50"> ---------one--------- </div>
                    <div fxFlex="50"> ---------two--------- </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item>
            <div matLine>
                <div fxLayout="column">
                    <div fxFlex="50"> ---------three---------</div>
                    <div fxFlex="50"> ---------four---------</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-list-item>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Have to say I dislike how they changed the perfectly working md-list of angularjs. This one kinda feels like a small hack.